# System of linear equations with positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: matrix-equations

There is a Lemma in paper "team decision problems" by Radner:
Lemma: If $C$ is a $K \times K$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, partitioned symmetrically into blocks $C_{ij}$ such that $C_{ii}$ is positive definite for every $i$, and if $Q$ is an $N \times N$ symmetric positive definite matrix with elements $q_{ij}$, then matrix $H$ composed of blocks $q_{ij}C_{ij}$ is positive definite.

Based on this lemma, it has concluded that the linear system:
$\sum_{j=1}^N Q_{ij}A_j S_{ji}= W_i$ for $i=1,...,N$, where $Q$ and $S$ matrices are positive definite, has a unique solution for $A_i$'s. In other words, the coefficients of $A_j$ in the equation are positive definite. Can any body tell me how we can conclude this from the Lemma?

Thanks

Comment: What is $W_i$? is a matrix, vector or ... ?

Comment: What are dimensions of $Q_{ij}$, $A_j$, $S_{ji}$ and $W_i$?

Comment: @MehdiJafarniaJahromi $Q_{ij}$ is $m \times m$, $A_j$ is $m \times s$, $S_{ji}$ is $s \times s$, and $W_i$ is $m \times s$.